# Securely Embedding Secret Key in Windows Phone 8 C# code

Tags: c#, security, windows-phone-8, secret-key

I am looking at various options to embed secret key in Windows Phone C# code, Windows App Analyzer tool is able to decompile the code and I was able to view the source code (http://sourceforge.net/projects/wpaa/)

I am gathering information about best practices for hiding/embedding secret key information within source code:

1) **Code Obfuscator:** http://www.ssware.com/articles/protect-and-obfuscate-your-dotnet-code-against-reverse-engineering-using-crypto-obfuscator.htm

2) **Safe guarding database connection strings:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164054.aspx

I understand that it is impossible to be 100% secure, but are there best practices specific to Windows Phone 8 that does not compromise on code readability yet provides certain level of obscurity/security?

Comment: Decompiling is not an issue if one can't get your app xap file.